# Pandas Dataframe override existing row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe exported to CSV, storing an index, username, and a string specific to the user. I want a function to edit the string of the user if they already exist in the database, and create a user if they don't. For example:

```
,User,String
0,Bob,Bob Is Cool
1,Joe,Joe Is Great
```

Adding `Joe` and `Joe is Smart` will make it:

```
,User,String
0,Bob,Bob Is Cool
1,Joe,Joe Is Smart
```

Adding `Jeff` and `Jeff is Good` will make it:

```
,User,String
0,Bob,Bob Is Cool
1,Joe,Joe Is Smart
2,Jeff,Jeff is Good
```

I tried using `in`. For Example:

```
if user in df.User:
```

```
if user in df.values:
```

And so on but I can't seem to get it to work. It always adds a new entry no matter what.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can set "User" to the dataframe index with `df = df.set_index('User')`, then simply use `df.loc[user, 'String'] = 'updated or new string'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` in pandas check the index of value instead of the value itself:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
>>> 'Bob' in data['User']
False
>>> 1 in data['User']
True
```

if you want to check if `Bob` exists in the dataframe you have to do this:

```
>>> 'Bob' in data['User'].values
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to

```
df.User.eq(user).any()
```

Comment: When I use a user that already exists, and when I use this condition, it still creates a new row in the dataframe. I'm using `if df.User.eq(user).any():` as my if statement. Any help?